# index.php in CakePHP i dont get it

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I don't know where something is wrong, the ZIP file was just been given to me, and a set of programmer 'did' the 'half' of the work, and now I should do it, the problem is, I don't know where the error is, nothing shows when I go to localhost/wookay/

Here's the code:

```
<?php

if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}



if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}


if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}

if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT);
}




if (!defined('WEBROOT_DIR')) {
    define('WEBROOT_DIR', basename(dirname(__FILE__)));
}

if (!defined('WWW_ROOT')) {
    define('WWW_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
}

if (!defined('CORE_PATH')) {
    if (function_exists('ini_set') && ini_set('include_path', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'))) {
        define('APP_PATH', null);
        define('CORE_PATH', null);
    } else {
        define('APP_PATH', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS);
        define('CORE_PATH', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS);
    }
}

if (!include(CORE_PATH . 'cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
    trigger_error("CakePHP core could not be found.  Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php.  It should point to the directory containing your " . DS . "cake core directory and your " . DS . "vendors root directory.", E_USER_ERROR);
}



if (isset($_GET['url']) && $_GET['url'] === 'favicon.ico') {

    return;
} else {

    $Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();

            $Dispatcher->dispatch($url);
    }

if (Configure::read() > 0) {
    echo "<!-- " . round(getMicrotime() - $TIME_START, 4) . "s -->";
}

?>
```

I forgot to tell you, I'm a bit noob on CakePHP, I usually use smarty template and create my own framework in the process, and I'm sure that the problem lies somewhere within the `$Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();` I echoed before and after, it didn't show whats after...

I Changed the config/core.php Configure::('debug',0); to Cinfigure::('debug',1);

When it was "0" nothing was showing, now, when I changed it to "1" everything is showing, but should 0 be production mode?

Comment: Check your web server's logs. The errors are likely there.

Comment: Backticks are for `inline code only`. For code blocks, indent each line by 4 spaces or select the block and press the `{}` button.

Comment: sadly it does not have an error log... :(

Comment: @GianCresciniSantillan Turn on error reporting and CakePHP's debug (set it to `2`) in `config.php`

Comment: `define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)`? "My constants are shorter than your constants" one-upmanship?

Comment: @Gian, share the steps you have already taken to solve this problem.  Effort = up votes.

Comment: @MarcB It's like that by default in CakePHP...go figure why they did it.

Comment: @MarcB Why not? `ROOT_PATH . DS . 'localhost' . DS . 'app' . DS . 'www' . DS` seems cleaner than `ROOT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . 'localhost' . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR . 'www' . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on error reporting, add this line after the opening `<?php`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

or enable CakePHP's debug setting by setting its value to `2` you'll do this in

```
config/core.php
```

then change this line to

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Comment: thanks, im really a noob here thank you, but i still have a problem, before i did, Conigure::write('debug',2); it was 0, nothing was showing, now i changed it to 2 everything is showing :(

Comment: @GianCresciniSantillan It is highly recommended to leave at `2` while working on your website but change it to `0` when you put it in production.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP set [it own error handler](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1188/Error-Handling) which prevents from save the logs where php usually will do.

What I recommend you is to go to `app/config/core.php` and check the option `debug` check [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/931/CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables) for an starting point to see where the problem is.

The main issue with cakephp is you usually start from a blind spot.

Answer (score 0):

at the top off the file add this line

```
echo "test";
```

Comment out the test of the file and then reload it.  You should see the word test in the browser.  Now, systamatically add small pieces of the code back into the file.  Meaning move the top comment anchor beneath the

```
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
```

code, save and refresh the page - repeat this process until the page fails, then you know where the problem is in the code.