# Why does my index page not appear unless debug is on in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I added the line:

```
Configure::write('debug', 1);
```

to the `config/core.php` script. It used to read:

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Prior to the change, the index file used to show nothing. When I changed it to `1`, everything showed up; the layout, the pages, the data, everything! What happened?

Comment: Well, you enabled debugging, see http://new.book.cakephp.org/view/1189/Debugging

Comment: Related: [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405367/index-php-in-cakephp-i-dont-get-it) (and you accepted an answer)

Answer (score 5):

CakePHP likes to cache things. Database schemas, file paths, etc. By enabling debug mode, CakePHP cleared its cache (by emptying the folders in `app/tmp/cache`) and regenerated them.

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405367/index-php-in-cakephp-i-dont-get-it), you were experiencing the "white screen of death" as errors were occuring in production mode. This is a safety feature to prevent your app from spilling information out about your server setup.

If your problems are now gone after a cache refresh, I imagine you may have initially caused the error by changing the database schema or moving files around when CakePHP was in production mode.

Answer (score 2):

From the config file (the default one):

```
/**
 * CakePHP Debug Level:
 *
 * Production Mode:
 *  0: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown. Flash messages redirect.
 *
 * Development Mode:
 *  1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.
 *  2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.
 *
 * In production mode, flash messages redirect after a time interval.
 * In development mode, you need to click the flash message to continue.
 */
```

So basically you turned the debug mode `on`, that includes **not stopping on errors**,  which was the case when it was set to `0`.

Comment: Please consider adding a comment if you're downvoting. I can always learn new things if you correct me.